# __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, ios10

I am getting this when uploading to server in this API I am uploading audio file and text data and if I remove audio it is working fine and I am getting this error in iOS 10. In iOS below 10 it's working fine all data is getting uploaded.

> Error: The request timed out. 2016-11-11 10:17:26.263019 Smart Child Info[1407:423623] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your request timed out, try (assuming you are using NSMutableURLRequest and you want a timeout of 120 seconds):

```
    request.timeoutInterval = 120;
```